# Bluetooth enabled, portable, battery powered, weighing scale for groceries weighing (commercial use)

Tags: wireless, smartphones, bluetooth, portable

I'm looking for a physical weighing scale/machine that allows the cashier to weigh different groceries (one at a time, of course) - and the weight be reflected via bluetooth* into the cashier's smartphone. The cashier would select the item on his/her phone, capture the weight from the weighing scale and correspondingly the total bill will be generated. This device needs to be portable, as the cashier is on a mobile cart.

The items being sold are loose (NOT packaged), so they will be placed in a temporary container tray (so the machine will need a "tare function" - ie, weighing of the empty container, followed by the weighing of the grocery item + tray, so only the difference is considered).

To summarize:

1. Physical weighing scale/machine to handle loose items by weight
2. Tare function (to subtract weight of holding tray)
3. Accuracy to 1 g level (ideal)
4. Commercial grade, meant for moderate daily use (~20-100 per day)
5. Able to handle upto 10-15 kg of products per instance
6. Bluetooth or similarly able to connect with smartphone app
7. Displays live weight data on smartphone
8. Live data can be accessed by our app on the smartphone
9. Light weight (as much as possible)
10. Battery powered (not requiring AC), able to last 8-10 hours with above usage

*Or another communication mechanism. It can be wired, but I'll need to understand how the two devices will be linked together.

Answer (score 1):

Products like this seem to exist in the market - which are bluetooth enabled weighing scales.

https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/pricing-scale-bluetooth-piece-counting-weighing_62434236667.html?spm=a2700.12243863.0.0.6d1f3e5fzskt31

https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Ocs-SP-Electronic-bluetooth-scale_60704151336.html?spm=a2700.icbuShop.41413.8.1a494554ojDVLM